# querySelectorAll() for all forms with addEventListener for different forms

Tags: javascript

Hello ladies and gentleman.

Currently I am trying to create a event listener to all forms that I have in my website, but... (I'm a backend developer so frontend it's nightmare for me) so now I'm trying to work with JavaScript (pure Vanilla JS) without any framework or nothing... and I use ES5.

So what I want to do is to send the name of the differents `<form>` that we have but I'm struggling so hard with this one because I am using the `querySelector('form')` and ***I JUST figured*** that it is not correct because it will only select one `<form>` so the correct way must use this `querySelectorAll('form')` BUT there's another problem by "standard" of my company we not define the name of the forms, so we "define" our forms with `action='/searchExample` currently we have about 32 nameless `<form>` and we only have two forms with name `login_form` and `registration` (only for those we defined the name)

```
   function formSubmitTrack() {
    var formName = '';
    var form = document.querySelector('form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
      formName = form.getAttribute('action')
        ? form.getAttribute('action')
        : form.getAttribute('name');

      var data = {
        event: 'e_formSubmit',
        formName: formName
      };

      send(data);
    });
```

I will be very grateful if someone can help me to this particular case because I don't want to create 32 `function form1...32()` for per `<form>` this code for example will apply for one form:

So I was trying to this one: (step 1 to capture the values)

```
function formSubmitTrackAll() {
      var form = document.querySelectorAll('form');

      for (let i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
          const element = form[i];
          var formName = element.name;
          var formAction = element.getAttribute('action');

          console.log(formName);
          console.log(formAction);

          if(formName === ""){
              var data = {
                  event: 'e_forSubmit',
                  formName: formAction,
              }
          } else {
            var data = {
                  event: 'e_forSubmit',
                  formName: formName,
              }
          }

          send(data);
      }
  }
```

so step 2, is to trigger the eventListener('click') for when the user clicks the form, this is my code but I'm confused whit this part for the `eventListener`:

```
function formSubmitTrackAll() {
      var form = document.querySelectorAll('form');

      for (let i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
          const element = form[i];
          var formName = element.name;
          var formAction = element.getAttribute('action');

          console.log(formName);
          console.log(formAction);

          if(formName === ""){
              formName.addEventListener('click', function() {
                var data = {
                    event: 'e_forSubmit',
                    formName: formAction,
                }
              })

          } else {
            formAction.addEventListener('click', function() {
                var data = {
                    event: 'e_forSubmit',
                    formName: formAction,
                }
              })
          }

          send(data);
      }
  }
```

and I use this HTML code to test

```
<form action="something">
    <input type="email"></input> 
    <button class="btn btn-safe col-xs-6"></button>
</form>
<br><br>

<form name='registration'>
    <button class="btn btn-security col-xs-6"></button>
</form>
```

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Does this help? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ku3f4L6h/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking.

```js
function formSubmitTrackAll() {
      var form = document.querySelectorAll('form');

      for (let i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
          const element = form[i];
          var formName = element.name;
        

          console.log(formName);
       

          if(formName === ""){
              form[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                var formAction = element.getAttribute('action');
                var data = {
                    event: 'e_forSubmit',
                    formName: formAction,
                }
                console.log(data);
              });

          } else {
            form[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
               var formAction = element.getAttribute('name');
                var data = {
                    event: 'e_forSubmit',
                    formName: formAction,
                }
                  console.log(data);
              });
          }

          //send(data);
      }
  }
  formSubmitTrackAll();
```

```html
<form action="something">
    <input type="email"></input> 
    <button class="btn btn-safe col-xs-6"></button>
</form>
<br><br>

<form name='registration'>
    <button class="btn btn-security col-xs-6"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your `send(data)` call to be inside of the click event handlers, not outside. As it currently stands, you're calling `send(data)` while looping through the forms instead.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I interpret your question correctly but I understand that you require that when sending a form, prior to being sent, obtain the event and name based on the conditions you mention. I assume that the form will be sent using POST so you can:

1. Get the data
2. Create hidden type inputs and assign them the corresponding data values
3. Attach these inputs to the form
4. Send the form

Please consider this example

Having this set of forms

```
<form name="login_form"><button type="submit">Send</button></form>
<form name="registration"><button type="submit">Send</button></form>
<form action="action_name1"><button type="submit">Send</button></form>
<form action="action_name2"><button type="submit">Send</button></form>
<form action="action_name3"><button type="submit">Send</button></form>
<form action="action_name4"><button type="submit">Send</button></form>
<form action="action_name5"><button type="submit">Send</button></form>
```

Given this logic

```
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');

function handleforms(forms) {
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        var data = { event: 'e_formSubmit' };
        var form = forms[i];

        data.name = form.hasAttribute('name') ? form.getAttribute('name') : form.getAttribute('action');

        form.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var eventInput = document.createElement('input');
            var nameInput = document.createElement('input');

            eventInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            eventInput.setAttribute('name', 'event');
            eventInput.setAttribute('value', data.event);

            nameInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            nameInput.setAttribute('name', 'name');
            nameInput.setAttribute('value', data.name);

            form.appendChild(eventInput);
            form.appendChild(nameInput);

            form.submit(); // In processing action ypu will have access to event and name 
        })
    }
}

handleforms(forms);
```

I hope it is useful for you